# Как создать класс с копией статических методов другого класса?

Tags: ооп, php

Есть класс Functions.

У него статические методы.

Нужно создать класс Html с копией методов класса Functions.

```
class Html extends Functions {

}
```

Можно ли как-то указать, какие именно методы должен наследовать класс Html?

В классе Html не требуются все методы класса Functions.

Answer (score 1):

> Нужно создать класс Html с копией методов класса Functions.

Вы делаете это в строчке

```
class Html extends Functions
```

---

> Можно ли как-то указать, какие именно методы должен наследовать класс Html?

Нет, наследуются все открытые (public) и защищенные (protected) методы.

---

> В классе Html не требуются все методы класса Functions.

Значит у вас где-то ошибка в логике построения иерархии.